# OrientDB Community Edition Synchronization

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

I am running OrientDB 2.2 Community Edition and I have already used teleporter to import a SQL database consisting of 22 tables and 11 million records. I dropped a vertex class as I needed to change something and when i went to reimport a table using teleporter i got this message...

ERROR: Synchronization not allowed in OrientDB CE. Execution will be terminated

Is there a way i can import this table and join it to the corresponding vertex classes already in the orientdb database without dropping the whole database and reimporting everything from scratch (which took about 5 hours)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronisation is not allowed in OrientDB Community Edition, but it is in OrientDB Enterprise Edition. Thus you just have 2 choices:

- try the OrientDB Enterprise Edition (45 days trial) and exploit the synch feature. Download link: http://orientdb.com/orientdb-enterprise/
- drop the old database and migrate you relational database again from scratch.

I Hope I was helpful.

Comment: **Synchronization**, what is this? What's mean in SqlServer?